# How often are "notable question" and "famous question" awarded without also getting "good" and "great" question?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was looking through my badges and noticed that I have a question for which I earned the Famous Question badge but I haven't even earned the Good Question badge.  Is it more common for questions to get the views related badges rather than the votes or vice-versa?

Comment: I have the same.... I don't have any good or great questions on SO, but several are notable and one is famous.  For views, titles and searchability are all that matter, but for the Good/Great questions, you really need to ask a good question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Another thing I wonder is how many views are from people linking from google (or other search engine) that don't even have SE accounts and can't quickly vote.

Comment: Questions with high views but low votes tend to be questions which are very searchable, but aren't useful to those with voting accounts. That could mean a number of things: 1) Attracts non-programmers who don't have accounts. 2) So basic that people who need it don't have voting accounts. 3) The title does not match the question and it's not what people are looking for.

Comment: It just occurred to me to look at the number of total badges there are.  It looks like there are 155200 famous questions but only 6700 good questions so I guess that answers that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have to look at the totals for each badge (and ignore any overlap) to see that Famous Question is awarded a *lot* more than Great Question.

[Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) awarded 155,204 times.
[Great Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question) awarded 6,748 times.

This is at least partially explained by search and social media traffic. A lot of views come from Google, reddit, Twitter, etc., and the people viewing the question may not have an account, or just not enough reputation to vote.

Answer (score 1):

One much more often 'view' the questions - you have tabs (newest, featured), tags, google etc... so even SO users may open and 'view' questions more often and not necessary 'vote' on them.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mysticial and @bill-the-lizard said, views by non-members (or those who aren't logged in) definitely impact that somewhat, however I'd hazard a guess that at least as many views are by members who simply didn't upvote the question.

I believe that I'm relatively generous with my upvotes, but many questions don't warrant it, and in my experience, many more members upvote answers than the corresponding questions.